# jquery star plugin not working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I have one JSP in that JSP i have a for loop. inside the for loop i am printing stars with rating in different cells of table. After making the ajax call, stars are not coming. Just the radio buttons are coming I am using this plugin http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/. Here is my step by step code. I have removed some part to make it simple.
First JSP code :

```
<div class="book-right" id="ajaxTest">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.rating.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<--table + some intermediate loop code --->
    <c:forEach var="leg" items="${option.legs}" varStatus="loopCounter3">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="rating-${loopCounter2.index}" value="1" class="rating-star" />
            <input type="radio" name="rating-${loopCounter2.index}" value="2" class="rating-star" />
            <input type="radio" name="rating-${loopCounter2.index}" value="3" class="rating-star" />
            <input type="radio" name="rating-${loopCounter2.index}" value="4" class="rating-star" />
            <input type="radio" name="rating-${loopCounter2.index}" value="5" class="rating-star" />
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="avgRating" name="avgRating" value="${leg.courierProduct.rating}"></input>

        <script>
            var avgRating = $('#avgRating').val();
            $('.rating-star').rating('select', avgRating);
        </script>
    </c:forEach>
```

Here is my ajax call :

```
function loadXMLDoc()
  {
    var xmlhttp;
    var filtervalue=document.getElementById('filter1').value;
    var url="FilterRender?filtervalue="+filtervalue;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("ajaxTest").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            var preference = document.getElementById("pref_id").value;
            if(preference== '1')
            {
                $("#myTable").tablesorter({
                    sortList  : [[2,0]],
                    headers: { 
                               0: { 
                                   sorter: false 
                                }, 
                                4: { 
                                    sorter: false 
                                } } });
            }
            else if(preference== '2')
            {
                $("#myTable").tablesorter({
                    sortList  : [[1,0]],
                    headers: { 
                        0: { 
                                 sorter: false 
                           }, 
                        4: { 
                                sorter: false 
                            } } });
            }
            else
                {
                 $("#myTable").tablesorter({  
                        headers: { 
                            //make the first column un-sortable
                           0: { 
                                 sorter: false 
                            }, 
                            //make the fourth column un-sortable
                            4: { 
                                sorter: false 
                            } } });
                }
           var avgRating = $('#avgRating').val();
            alert('called');
            $('.rating-star').rating().rating('select', avgRating ); 
            $('.rating-star').rating('readOnly',true);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

After the Ajax call i am loading this div:

```
<div class="book-right" id="ajax">
             <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.rating.js"></script> 
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
                <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${fn:length(routes) == 1 and fn:length(routes[0].options) == 0}">
                 <div style="padding:216px;width:800px !important">
                 <span style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bolder;margin: 90px;">Sorry! Currently we have no service found for this route.</span>
                </div>
                </c:when>
                 <c:otherwise>  
            <table  id="myTable" class="tablesorter" width="769" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="sortable">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th  width="24%" height="67" align="center" bgcolor="#f7f6f6">
                                <span class="ser service"> Service Provider</span>
                            </th>
                            <th width="21%" height="67" align="center" bgcolor="#f7f6f6">
                                <span class = "ser icon1 icon2" >Delivery Time
                                </span>
                            </th>
                            <th width="16%" height="67" align="center" bgcolor="#f7f6f6">
                                <span class = "ser icon1 icon3">Cost
                                </span>
                            </th>
                             <th width="15%" height="67" bgcolor="#f7f6f6" align="center">
                                <span class="ser">Ratings </span>
                            </th> 
                            <th width="17%" height="67" align="center" bgcolor="#f7f6f6">
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
      <c:set var="filtervalue" scope="session" value="${param.filtervalue}"/>  

                        <c:forEach var="route" items="${routes}" varStatus="loopCounter">
                            <c:forEach var="option" items="${route.options}"
                                varStatus="loopCounter2">
                                <tr>
                                <c:if test="${option.duration<=filtervalue}">
                                    <td><div>
                                            <c:forEach var="leg" items="${option.legs}"
                                                varStatus="loopCounter3">
                                                <span class="item"> <img
                                                    src="img/vendor_logos/<c:out value="${leg.courierProduct.logoName}" />"></span>
                                            </c:forEach>
                                        </div></td>
                                    <td><span><c:out value="${option.duration}" />&nbsp; days</span></td>
                                    <td><span class="cost" style="font-size: 23px;"><img
                                            src="img/rs.png">
                                        <c:out value="${option.totalCost}" />/-</span></td>
                          <td>
                          <c:forEach var="leg" items="${option.legs}" varStatus="loopCounter3">
                          <div>
                          <input type="radio" name="rating-${loopCounter2.index}" value="1" class="rating-star"/>
                          <input type="radio" name="rating-${loopCounter2.index}" value="2" class="rating-star"/>
                          <input type="radio" name="rating-${loopCounter2.index}" value="3" class="rating-star"/>
                          <input type="radio" name="rating-${loopCounter2.index}" value="4" class="rating-star"/>
                          <input type="radio" name="rating-${loopCounter2.index}" value="5" class="rating-star"/>
                        </div>
                            <input type= "hidden" id="avgRating" name="avgRating" value= "${leg.courierProduct.rating}"></input>
                            <script>
                            var avgRating = $('#avgRating').val();
                            alert('called');
                            $('.rating-star').rating().rating('select', avgRating ); 
                            $('.rating-star').rating('readOnly',true) 
                            </script>
                            </c:forEach>
                            </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <div id="${loopCounter2}" class="details"  >

                                            <span class="det"><a href="#">Details</a>
                                                <span class="fulv">
                                                    <div class="col">
                                                     <p>Cost - Rs-<c:out value="${option.cost}" /></p>
                                                     <p>Service Tax - Rs - <c:out value="${option.serviceTax}"/></p>
                                                     <p>Total - Rs - <c:out value="${option.totalCost}"/></p>
                                                    </div><!--ocl-->
                                                </span><!--fulv-->
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="book"><a
                                                href="BookingConfirmAction?routeIndex=${loopCounter.index}&routeOptionIndex=${loopCounter2.index }">Book Now</a></span>

                                        </div>

                                        <!--details-->
                                    </td>
                                    </c:if>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                            <!-- <br> -->
                        </c:forEach>

                    </tbody>
                </table>    
                </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>             
            </div>
```

I have given the full second JSP code (loaded by AJAX) for reference. I am a beginner.Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please ask if any more code needs to be shown

Comment: alert('called') is not fired even for a single time (after ajax call). So the JS is not called at all after ajax. Please help.

Comment: add your rating jquery code at last in  `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)`

Comment: after see your ajax response you already call rating function . so no need to add in ajax complete .

Comment: also remove all script tag which load all js files . as it already loaded in main file

Comment: sorry for chat .. its blocked at my work place :)

Comment: Its okay sir.. but can you please suggest something. rating function is called for the radio buttons but it is disappearing after that. :P